# Sentence case formatting in c#

Tags: c#, regex

i would like to change the case of a string in "Sentence case". I've use this function:

```
private string toSentenceCase(string sourcestring)
{
    var lowerCase = sourcestring.ToLower();

    lowerCase = Regex.Replace(lowerCase, @"(\r\n|\n\r|\n|\r)", "\r\n");
    var r = new Regex(@"(^[a-z])|[?!.\r\n]\s+(.)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
    var result = r.Replace(lowerCase, s => s.Value.ToUpper());

    return result;
}
```

with my regex expression i would like to catch the puncture '.', '?', '!' and also '\n' and '\r'. My code works except if there is no "whitespace" character between sentence. 
For example
"First example. there is white space." becomes "First example. There is white space."
But
"Second example.there is white space." remains "Second example.there is white space."

Any idea on how to change my regex expression to catch also the second example?

Answer (score 3):

Just turn `\s+` to `\s*`, since `\s+` must expect a space character where `\s*` won't.

```
var r = new Regex(@"(^[a-z])|[?!.\r\n]\s*(.)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```

**OR**

```
var r = new Regex(@"(?:^|[?!.\r\n])\s*([a-z])", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture);
```